# Changing the response type of WEB API

Tags: json, linq, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a WEB API using `MySQL` DB. The API is working well. The code is below

```
try
        {
            var before = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
            var after = dt.AddMinutes(5);

            var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd
                         .Where(m =>
                         m.zdjh == msn &&
                         m.sjsj >= before &&
                         m.sjsj <= after).Select(m => new { MSN = m.zdjh, DateTime = m.sjsj, Signal_Strength = m.xhqd }).Distinct();


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = result });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
```

and the response is below

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "MSN": "002999000076",
        "DateTime": "2017-10-11T10:16:48",
        "Signal_Strength": "15"
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999000076",
        "DateTime": "2017-10-11T10:19:02",
        "Signal_Strength": "15"
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999000076",
        "DateTime": "2017-10-11T10:20:58",
        "Signal_Strength": "16"
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999000076",
        "DateTime": "2017-10-11T10:22:54",
        "Signal_Strength": "15"
    }
]}
```

**How's it working?**

I am passing a meter serial number and a date time. The API receives both of them. +- The minutes in time and display all the records withing that time.

Now I want is that, If at a particular time there exist any record then the API will send me `YES` in response and if no record is found then it will send me `NO`.

The sample response should be

```
{
    "data": [
        {
         "Response":   "YES"/"NO"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have searched a solution for it but couldn't able to find one

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: so basically you are checking a result with in -5 to +5 range for the time right?

Comment: Yes i am checking that way

Comment: what is the type of `medEntitites` ?

Comment: I have declared it `public MDCEntities medEntitites = new MDCEntities();`

Answer (score 1):

Create the below class

```
public class ResponseChecker
{
    public string Response{get; set;};

    public ResponseChecker(IEnumerable result)
    {
        if(result.ToList().Count > 0)
            Response = "YES";
        else
            Response = "NO";
    }
}
```

Modify your code as below

```
try
{
    var before = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
    var after = dt.AddMinutes(5);

    var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd
                 .Where(m =>
                 m.zdjh == msn &&
                 m.sjsj >= before &&
                 m.sjsj <= after).Select(m => new { MSN = m.zdjh, DateTime = m.sjsj, Signal_Strength = m.xhqd }).Distinct();


    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = new ResponseChecker(result) });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
}
```

Comment: getting this error `IEnumerable does not contain a definition for ToList and no extension method ToList accepting a first argument of type IEnumerable could be found` at `if(result.ToList().Count > 0)`

Comment: Your code is working but it is giving me "Yes" in response always whether the sending parameters are correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var before = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
var after = dt.AddMinutes(5);

bool anyRecords = medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Any(m =>
     m.zdjh == msn &&
     m.sjsj >= before &&
     m.sjsj <= after);

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new 
{ 
    data = new[]
    {
        new { Response = anyRecords ? "YES" : "NO" }
    }
});
```

*The response seems a little excessive to me. Why do you need a single-element array of objects just to return a single flag?*